# Inkscape: filter on the background as fill color

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to generate diagrams for my blog in Inkscape that are equally suitable for dark and light schemes. The background color of the HTML page is #ffffff in light mode and #424242 in dark mode. I use CSS to invert all images when the color mode changes to dark.

I use a transparent background for my diagram objects, so their color switches to #424242 automatically when in dark mode. Now, I want to create objects that are darker than the background in light mode and lighter in dark mode. That is, the background of these objects is a filter on the background color.

Is this possible in Inkscape and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up CSS styles in Inkscape using *Extensions > Styles > Merge Styles into CSS*.  Select one or more objects (with the same styles obviously) before running the extension.

Here's an example optimised SVG output (no edits). A simple rectangle with a fill. I named the style MyStyle. Obviously there are a few attributes within it which could be removed with a text editor. Since I used no stroke, everything except the fill could just be deleted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><style><![CDATA[
.MyStyle {
  fill:#333333;
  paint-order:stroke fill markers;
  stroke:none;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:1.165;
}
]]></style></defs><rect class="MyStyle" x="11.11" y="11.82" width="40.13" height="38.69"/></svg>
```

Comment: So, to apply this to my use-case, I have to add the dark-theme style with the rule `html[data-scheme="dark"] .MyStyle`, then define the colors according to the website style sheet, am I correct?

Comment: HTML coding is generally off-topic here.  Better to ask on Stack Overflow how to implement it on a web page.

Comment: Yea, it sure is. By the way, Inkscape doesn't offer any built-in way to define more than 1 colorscheme, right?

Comment: @Green绿色 You can create as many CSS classes as you like, but Inkscape doesn't have anything resembling colour schemes.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.